# difference tun/tap, is the interfaces that handle protocols or the OS?

Tags: linux, networking, tap, bridge, tun

I have difficulties to understand difference between tap and tun interface. I know it is an often asked question and I apologize for that.

I read tap work at layer 2 and tun works at layer 3. I also read that tap is used for bridging and tun is used for routing.
I already heard things like "ROUTERS work at layer 3" or "BRIDGES work at layer 3" : this make sense for me because routers manipulate layer 3 protocols and bridge manipulate layer 2 protocols?
but, because tap and tun are "interfaces", it means the sentence like "INTERFACES work at layer 3" has a sense but i don't understand what it is : I mean interfaces doesn't manipulate protocols(the OS do that but not an interface) so it sounds like tun interface == tap interface:

If I create two tap interfaces(with tunctl) with two ip that are on different networks (192.168.2.1/24 and 192.168.3.1/24), then I link these to two kvm virtual machine (one tap interface match to one VM) and if I enable routing on the host, my two VM can communicate.

So tap interfaces can also be used for routing : what is the difference with tun ? maybe a tap is also a tun interface?

Also I can create a tap interface with tunctl command but how can I create a tun interface with the same command(the command is called TUNctl not TAPctl...)?

Can you help me to clarify that?
Thank you.

Comment: I think the community in general and you too would benefit, should you spend some time reading about [what topics are welcome here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please consider closing your question and asking it instead in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/). To answer your question, the difference is this: a TUN device is a virtual ethernet adapter whereas a TAP device is a virtual point-to-point IP link (in case these don't make sense, ask your search engine what is the difference between point-to-point ip link and an ethernet).

Comment: "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. " ok you're all right I'm sorry. Because of your answer i did (and i continue) research about point-to-point ip link and an ethernet link but it still not clear : it seems ethernet can be a point-to-point link(and not broadcast link) and with ip i can do broadcast. I will ask ly question in Unix & Linux .

Comment: you can close this question if you want. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155415/difference-tun-tap-is-the-interfaces-that-handle-protocols-or-the-os

Comment: @user21992104: This might help...
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt

Comment: **Cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155415/difference-tun-tap-is-the-interfaces-that-handle-protocols-or-the-os**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cross-site dupe.